# API Endpoint Design : Technical Spec or Product

Tags: rest, restful-url

We have 2 developers who have conflicts in the way to design the RESTful API Endpoint. Basically, let say that we have Facebook product in hand, one table for the posts.

**First developer** give the opinions that

- We should seperate Endpoint by product, not by the technical storage. To be like that, we will have endpoint for user facebook post and other facebook post.

`/v1/wall/mypost`

`/v1/wall/other`

- To be like that, we be able to configure each products that may return difference results

**Second developer** disagree, give the opinions that

- If be like that, it will make infinite endpoint. it will have `/wall/someone`, `/wall/sometwo`.
- We should have single endpoint, and just let that be a part of query. ex. `/wall?user=someone`, `/wall?user=sometwo`
- The endpoint should be look like technical schema, it return the same result, why it have to seperated to make it more jobs on maintenance the code.

What is the good practice to design our endpoint? Is it should be endpoint by the product? or is it should be by schema?

Answer (score 0):

It should depend on what 'resource' that the service is suppose to manage from the API user perspective and not from the internal implementation.

With that, if the service is to manage say, a resource that can be identified by 'someone', 'sometwo' and, then the correct way to model it is

/wall/someone/

/wall/sometwo/

In this case, 'someone' and 'sometwo' are two different resources and you could have infinite # of them; but that has nothing to do with the internal storage or implementation.

On the backend, there should be some url pattern to extract 'someone' and 'sometwo' as resource and  map them into internal implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

What are these "endpoints" you speak of? That's SOAP terminology! RESTful web services are defined in terms of "resources" that are uniquely identified by URL.

A resource typically represents an entity in your domain model (e.g., a user). The ID of the entity is typically used as a path element ("path parameter" in the lingo of most REST libraries, such as JAX-RS) in the URL. Query parameters should only be used to sort/filter results on the server side.

Your first developer is closer to being correct.